# SSE (Server Sent Events) Client library for Clojure?

Tags: clojure, client, server-sent-events

I would like to handle a **Server Sent Events stream** in Clojure. 
Does anyone know a small *client* library to just do that please ?

I was expecting to find something like https://github.com/stalefruits/gniazdo, which is for *Websockets*, but for *SSE*.

I could not find anything though and the only lib that may have been a good candidate is not maintained anymore https://github.com/clojurewerkz/ssese

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some overviews on the topic:

- https://sweetcode.io/using-html5-server-sent-events/
- https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/course-notes.html
- https://www.lucagrulla.com/posts/server-sent-events-with-ring-and-compojure/
- [Server push of data from Clojure to ClojureScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823002/server-push-of-data-from-clojure-to-clojurescript)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Here is a **highly voted comparison on StackOverflow** between Server Sent Events and WebSockets (my favorite):

- [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)

And here is a nice comparison from IBM (2017):

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-http-server-push-with-websocket-sse/index.html

Comment: AFAICS whilst an interesting round up of links, none of this answers the OP question for a clojure SSE cloent library.

Answer (score 0):

[immutant.web](http://immutant.org) has support for SSE built in: http://immutant.org/documentation/current/apidoc/guide-web.html#h3155

There is also this middleware for other web servers: https://github.com/kumarshantanu/ring-sse-middleware, although I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Request is for an SSE *client* not a server implementation.